# Non-deterministic image attribute data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm creating a very simple image gallery that relies on some JavaScript to size the images within the browser window. I have this piece of code:

```
$('img').each( function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height()
    var windowWidth = $(window).width()
    var imgHeight = $(this).height()
    var imgWidth = $(this).width()

    console.log("wh: " + windowHeight + "  ww: " + windowWidth)
    console.log("ih: " + imgHeight + "  iw: " + imgWidth)
}
```

When I load up a page with three images, the values are reported correctly, e.g.:

```
"wh: 1132  ww: 1650"
"ih: 3456  iw: 4608"
"wh: 1132  ww: 1650"
"ih: 3264  iw: 1836"
"wh: 1132  ww: 1650"
"ih: 3264  iw: 1836"
```

As soon as I refresh that same page (loaded as a local resource), the numbers are suddenly way off:

```
"wh: 706  ww: 1650"
"ih: 24  iw: 24"
```

Now I can reload it as many times as I want, the image height and width will never be reported correctly. However, when I rename the page or change its location, all is well on the first load again.

I assume this has something to do with caching but can't figure out how to prevent this from happening. I obviously don't care if the browser caches the images but why would that affect their attributes when the page is reloaded? Any ideas on why this behaves the way it does?

Comment: Is the DOM fully loaded by the time your JS runs?

Comment: @Siguza This is defined after `$(document).ready(function(){` so I assume yes.

Comment: *after*, or inside the function?

Comment: Should be inside `$(window).on('load', function(){...});` not document pseudo ready handler. Now i cannot really understand what's going wrong. Post a jsFiddle replicating issue.

Comment: Have you tried to disable cache just to be sure this has anything to do with  it ? I have my doubts on this...

Comment: @Purag Inside the function.

Comment: When/where does this code run exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As A. Wolff allready says, you need to run your code when all images are fully loaded.

jQuery-Documentation:

Run a function when the page is fully loaded including graphics.

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  // Run code
});
```

Comment: Ha, that's correct! Thank you! Out of curiosity, why is the first load different from the next ones in that it loads everything and only then runs the code?

Comment: Do you mean the difference between $(window).load() and $(document).ready()?

Comment: No, I mean the difference between the first load and a second load. If the images are not loaded in time when $(document).ready() is used, why did it work every time on the first load but not on the next ones (i.e. when that same page was refreshed)?

Comment: I suspect that is the cache. Maybe the browserrefresh force to relaod the image. I do not know exactly.